# UITableviewCell issue while scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I Have created the table view dynamically, In cellForRowAtIndexPath i have added one custom button on cell as a subview

```
if ([deviceNameArray count]!=0)
{
    pairButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    pairButton.frame = CGRectMake(230.0f, 10.0f, 70.0f, 25.0f);
    [pairButton setTitle:@"Connect" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pairButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pairButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    pairButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:10];

    pairButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [pairButton addTarget:self action:@selector(connectToDevice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:pairButton];
    isPairButtonAdded = YES;

}
```

I have changed the device the button title as disconnect after successful with my another Device. Now the problem is whenever am scrolling my table disconnect turning into connect but i dont want happen like that,i know its due to cell recreation how to stop recreating cell.

Comment: Put the whole implementation of – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to store record of connected and disconnected device in array and then you can manage your cell like this

```
if ([deviceNameArray count]!=0)
{
    pairButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    pairButton.frame = CGRectMake(230.0f, 10.0f, 70.0f, 25.0f);

    if([device isConnected]) // Get object from array and check is it coonected or disconnected
    {
       [pairButton setTitle:@"Connect" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [pairButton setTitle:@"Disconnected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
pairButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pairButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
pairButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:10];

pairButton.tag = indexPath.row;

[pairButton addTarget:self action:@selector(connectToDevice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:pairButton];
isPairButtonAdded = YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
// dequeue cell
if (!cell) {
    // create cell
}
// create button
```

Rather, you have to create the button inside the cell create block. Otherwise a new button will be created again each time the cell comes on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just i got solved the issue, crating my button inside condition where i am checking

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if ([deviceNameArray count]!=0)
    {
        pairButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        pairButton.frame = CGRectMake(230.0f, 10.0f, 70.0f, 25.0f);
        [pairButton setTitle:@"Connect" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        pairButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        pairButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        pairButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:10];

        pairButton.tag = indexPath.row;

        [pairButton addTarget:self action:@selector(connectToDevice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:pairButton];
        isPairButtonAdded = YES;

    }
```

now its solved